# How to setText() into not enabled JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, date, format, jformattedtextfield

I've got problem trying to setText into my JFormattedTextField when it is not enabled. It's all right, when it is... String value is not empty, but the field stays empty.

```
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy") {
    @Override
    public Date parse(String source) throws ParseException {
        return (source != null && !source.trim().equals("") && !source.trim().equals(".  .")) ? super.parse(source) : null;
    }
};


  ...
        jFormattedTextField1 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
`enter code here`...
    jFormattedTextField1.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(mf));
            jFormattedTextField2.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(mf));
            jFormattedTextField1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    super.mouseClicked(e);
                    showPopup(jFormattedTextField1);
                }
            });
        `jFormattedTextField1.setText("22.10.2012");`
```

Comment: MaskFormatter mf = new MaskFormatter("##.##.####");

Comment: So you're saying there is code that you have omitted?  It's hard to tell what's going on when you've only shown us part of the code.  Can you please edit the question to give us all the information we need?

Comment: sure. but i found, that there is no text only when jFormattedTextField1 is not Enabled

Comment: sorry, the class too long

Comment: Well, I'm not clever enough to find bugs in code that isn't shown.  Sorry. All I can do is suggest that you use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prolem was with Look and Feel Nimbus. The colour of text and TextField is the same

Answer (score 0):

just use Apache `StringUtils.isBlank` or `StringUtils.isNotblank` quite handy instead checking for null or empty.